# Validating data

Tags: java, dependencies, validation

I've got two validator classes. Let's say: Car Validator and Wheel validator, and the second one is enclosed in first.

```
CarBodyValidator.validate(){
    WheelValidator.validate();
}
```

I have more validators in CarBodyValidator, f.e EngineValidator etc. validate() should only return true or false, and at one time I want to print as many mistakes as possible (if validation returns false for some class, I want to validate other classes if they are not dependent on each other).
Now, let's say that Wheel validator returns a useful information, that I need in the CarBody validator. F.e if wheel diameter is too big then I need that info in car validator to validate something else. 
How do I pass that information. I could create a field in Wheel validator, that stores the parameter, but accessing it like that:

```
carBodyValidator.validate(){
    wheelValidator.validate();
    if (WheelValidator.getSmomething() == somethingElse){
      ...
    }

}
```

seems wrong (I mean validator should only validate and not do anything else). Is this the correct way or I should do it different.

Comment: Are you using a specific validation API?

Comment: No, I use my own validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this I often rely on the observer pattern.  Please note this is all pseudo code.

**Create a ValidatorObserver interface.**

```
public interface ValidatorObserver{
   public void notify(int errorKey);
}
```

**Make CarBodyValidator implement this interface.**

```
public class CarBodyValidator implements ValidatorObserver{

    public void notify(int errorKey){
       switch(errorKey){
         //Evaluate cases and do something.
       }
    }
}
```

**Create a register method on  WheelValidator and setup notification**

```
public class WheelValidator{
    private List<ValdiatorObserver> observers = new ArrayList<ValidatorObserver>();

    public void addObserver(ValidatorObserver observer){
       observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void validate(){
       //if validation fails
       for(ValidationObserver observer: observers){
          observers.notify(1); //1 is an error code
       }
    }
}
```

**Somewhere in your code you will need to register the observer**

```
CarBodyValiator cbValidator = new CarBodyValidator();
WheelValidator wheelValidator = new WheelValidator();
wheelValidator.addObserver(cbValidator);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. One is like you said. Let validate() returns a boolean and keep a Set of errors that happened during the validation. You can later ask for these errors if you need to.

A more elegant solution could be to have validate() method to return an instance of a specific class called ValidationResults. This class could contain the validation status and the Set of errors.

A third option could be to throw exceptions in validate(). Although there are people against this method since is not recommended to use Exceptions to decide the execution flow of your application I found it useful in some situations.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Throwing an exception would do what the OP wants to avoid: interrupting the validation process when a single validation fails.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good application for the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

It means that you have an object (the visitor) which is passed to each validator. The validators report their error messages to the visitor and/or pass it to further sub-validators which do the same.

The visitor stores all the error messages passed to it. Afterwards you can read the error messages the visitor collected and handle them in any way you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a boolean that indicates whether the validation passed or not, you could throw an exception if the object is not valid:

```
public void validateCar(Car car) throws ValidationException {
    if (car.getEngine() == null) throw new ValidationException("Engine is null", "engine");
}
```

The ValidationException contains the faulty field, which can then be reused in another validator.

But to me it seems that calling another validator when you know that the object is not valid seems a bit wrong. Perhaps you should merge these two validators and make it return a list of invalid fields?